# MySQL query works directly in MYSQL but when running within php i get an error due to running a set query first

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run the following script within my PHP script to calculate a running total.

```
<?php // Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "set @csum := 0; select  date(`DATE`) as dadate,  Price , (@csum := @csum + Price) as cumulative_sum from Profits WHERE Strat = 'arm' order by dadate;";
$result = $conn->query($sql)or die($conn->error);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo "{time: '" . $row["Date"]. "', value: ".$row["cumulative_sum"]. "},<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close(); ?>
```

I believe I am getting the error below because I am running 2 queries at once but am only supposed to execute one query at a time.

> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'select date(`daDATE`), Price ,
>   (@csum := @csum + Price) as cumulative_' at line 1

Is there any way around this is a need to set :csum to 0 to ensure it starts from 0

Comment: What PHP function do you use to run this SQL?
Please show the relevant code.

Comment: Move variable init into FROM clause.

Comment: Instead of using a variable to sum the prices you could use a [grouping function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html). More so, that is the way you should be doing it, and you would only need one query.

Comment: `mysqli::query` can only submit one query at a time. You would need to submit those separately, or use https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: @Akina I see, yes, I was only thinking about the total sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, this is incorrect, but I cannot find an example of it not working (in MySQL versions prior to 8.0)...

```
SELECT DATE(`daDATE`) date
     , Price
     , (@csum := @csum + Price) as cumulative_sum 
  from Profits 
     , (SELECT @csum := 0) vars 
 WHERE Strat = 'arm' 
 ORDER 
    BY daDATE;
```

Note that because you're passing the result to application code, you could just ad easily handle the cumulative arithmetic there

Comment: *Strictly speaking, this is incorrect* Why? the only reason may be that the processing order is not described in the documentation... but the source code shows that the records are processed strictly in the order set by ORDER BY clause.

Comment: That works great. I didn't know I can include another select within the from , thanks!

Comment: @Akina You're supposed to put the declaration elsewhere, but it only becomes apparent when, say, ordering by rand(). If and when I recall the correct method, I'll update accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Another initialization variant (without SELECT, primarily useful for UPDATE if you need it to be single-table):

```
SELECT DATE(`daDATE`) date
     , Price
     , (@csum := @csum + Price) as cumulative_sum 
  from Profits
 WHERE Strat = 'arm' 
   AND (@csum := 0) = 0
 ORDER 
    BY daDATE;
```